# Server Requirements For Razor/CSHTML (MVC 3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Like the title states what are the requirements for me to run this site online? I thought looking for a simple ASP host would be sufficient but it doesnt load correctly.

Example: http://mydb.x10.mx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need, at minimum, a host that has ASP.NET 4.0 installed.  It's also beneficial to have a site with MVC 3 installed already, but if you must you can upload the necessary DLL's to your bin folder.

More than likely, you have a host with only .net 2.x or 3.x installed.

Comment: is there anywhere that meets these rquirements that you know off hand? i can only find ASP.NET 3.5 Hosts.

Answer (score 0):

As Mystere Man stated, ASP.Net 4.0 is what you need, but if they don't have that, in your project, you can select the references for the missing segments (such as the System.Web.MVC [version 4.0.*]) and set the 'Copy Local' to true, that will ensure that on any further publishing the other parts are included (until your host updates to .net 4 and mvc3 or you find a better hosting solution)